# Azure Hyperledger Fabric Single Member Blockchain setup

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm starting to use Azure to host a multi node Hyperledger network. I've previously been running on a local environment, but would like to use Azure. I've deployed the 'Hyperledger Fabric Single Member Blockchain' template, which creates five VM's (one each for a CA, orderer and three peers). My local environment uses a CLI, but this doesn't seem to be in the Azure template. How do i interact with the blockchain network without the CLI?

Are there any tuturials for how to use the deployed environment after its been setup?

I've SSH'd to all of the three VM's that are hosting the peers, there seems to be an error with the docker container that has been automatically setup by deploying the Azure template. Running 'docker ps' shows that they are restarting reguarly, and i can't connect using the command docker exec -it  bash (i get an error saying that its restarting). Eg:

CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
817bbb256e5b hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha "peer node start -..." 7 hours ago Restarting (2) 6 seconds ago sad_clarke

Does anyone have the Hyperledger Fabric Single Member Blockchain template working?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Please do some formatting also some codes

Comment: @Paul X you could use this [link](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-blockchain-service?tab=Overview) to deploy.  At step `Summary`, you could edit the template.

Comment: @Walter - MSFT, yes this is the template that i have deployed to Azure. When you say 'edit the template' at the summary step, what edits should i make?

Comment: @Ironic, in relation to formatting are you referring to the docker ps dump? the relevant item is Status = 'Restarting (2) 6 seconds ago'

Comment: Did u finally find any answer ?

Comment: @SSR no, i gave up on Azure as i had no feedback from MSFT

Comment: I tried for two days and could not figure out . And documentation indicated it is only single host infra and not multi host production capable .

Comment: Others have reported this too. I found that this happens when you reboot the node that the CA is on.

Answer (score 1):

To interact with Hyperledger on Azure, you may indeed ssh into one of the VMs. Once there, you can use `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` to get a prompt in the the docker image running on that VM (ca, peer or orderer). In there you can issue commands.

I got the docker restarting error you mentioned after rebooting the VMs (but not immediately after deployment). I believe there is a bug in the MS deployment script. The `configure-fabric-azureuser.sh` uses `cacert="/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${PEER_ORG_DOMAIN}-cert.pem"` but after replacing with `cacert="/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/`**`ca`**`.${PEER_ORG_DOMAIN}-cert.pem"` all my problems with docker image restarting or running Hyperledger Composer tutorial were gone. I posted a fix on https://github.com/fabienpe/azure-hyperledger-artifacts

Have you checked the `config.log` files on each VM?