# Deploy chaincode to Hyperledger Fabric Consortium on Azure

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric, azure-blockchain-workbench

I've a single node Hyperledger Fabric network running on MS Azure, deployed using the [Hyperledger Fabric consortium network template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/blockchain/templates/hyperledger-fabric-consortium-blockchain#about-blockchain) from Azure. How do I deploy chaincodes to the network? After sshing to the VM, I can connect to the peers but when I try installing a chaincode I get `Error: error getting chaincode code car.go: <go, [env]>: failed with error: "exec: not started"`
I sense I'm doing something wrong. How do I deploy chaincodes to a fabric network deployed using the Azure Hyperledger Fabric template? 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149777/azure-hyperledger-fabric-single-member-blockchain-setup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902968/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-composer-to-azure-hyperledger-single-member-blockchai?rq=1) , not sure these are what I'm looking for. I just need to simply install and instantiate a chaincode using the peer cli.
Please help. Thank you.